# SQLException 32104 in OCCI

Tags: c++, c++17, occi

I am trying to use OCCI to connect my program to an oracle database but I am getting an SQLException 32104 when I try the createEnvironment function.

My code:

```
#include <OpenXLSX.hpp>
#include <occi.h>
#include <string>

using namespace OpenXLSX;
using namespace oracle::occi;

int main() {

    std::string user = "";
    std::string pass = "";
    std::string conn_str = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.2.159)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=test)))";

    std::cout << "Initializing Database Connection ......" << std::endl;

    try {
        Environment* env = Environment::createEnvironment(Environment::DEFAULT);
        //Connection *conn = env->createConnection(user, pass ,conn_str);
    } catch(SQLException &e) {
        std::cout << "Error Message: " << e.getErrorCode() << std::endl;
        std::cout << e.getMessage() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Initializing Database Connection ......";
    

    std::cout << " OK" << std::endl;

    XLDocument doc;
    doc.open("Template.xlsx");
    auto wks = doc.workbook().worksheet("Extruder Data Log");

    int row_number = 4;
    char column_letter = 'A';
    char column_letter2 = 'A';
    std::string loc;

    loc = column_letter;
    loc += std::to_string(4);

    wks.cell(loc).value() = "Hello, OpenXLSX!";

    doc.save();
    //env->terminateConnection(conn);
    //Environment::terminateEnvironment(env);

    std::cout << "Program Terminated: Press Enter ...";
    std::string wait;
    std::cin >> wait;

    return 0;
}
```

I am using CMake to compile:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(Atlas)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# Set the build output location to a common directory
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/output)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/output)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/output)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/lib)

add_subdirectory(OpenXLSX)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/include/OpenXLSX/headers)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/include/OpenXLSX)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/include/OCCI)
link_directories(${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
find_package(OpenXLSX REQUIRED)
find_library(OCCI NAMES oraocci21.lib oci.lib oramysql.lib oraocci21d.lib ociw32.lib)

add_executable(Atlas Atlas.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Atlas OpenXLSX::OpenXLSX)
target_link_libraries(Atlas ${OCCI})
```

I have the dlls in the output directory where the executable and libraries end up outputting to.
I figure that it should run, but I am getting a Microsoft C++ exception: oracle::occi::SQLException
and on debugging it shows that it is message 32104 which I know means that it cannot get the error.

The Debug window show that it loads the oraocci21.dll but not any of the other OCCI dlls.

If anyone can let me know what I'm doing wrong I would be incredibly grateful since I have scoured the internet trying to figure this out.

**EDIT**

Figured out this error, I hadn't moved all of the dlls from the instant client. I was only including the dlls that corresponded to the library names.
I included ocijdbc21.dll, orannzsbb.dll, and oraociicus.dll to the folder with my executable and it now runs past the createEnvironment(Environment::DEFAULT) part.

With this edit, though, I am now running into Error 24960 which says that OCI_ATTR_USERNAME is more than length 255 which it is not.
If anyone can help with that please let me know but I hope that anyone else running across this who needs help sees the part about the dlls.

If it helps to answer my question, I am using instant client base 21_3 and sdk 21_3. I am also using MSVC 16 2019 for compilation with C++17 as the version of C++. My Oracle Database is running on 19c and I can connect to it remotely.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out.
I was using this command for cmake:
`cmake --build . --target ALL_BUILD --config Debug`

This release config command should work because I have debugged the program:
`cmake --build . --target ALL_BUILD --config Release`

For some reason, I can only assume that OCCI did not like my debugger
version or something like that. If someone could please comment on why this happens I would like to learn.